# Why is $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$ a vector space of the dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $n,p \in \mathbb{N}$ whereby $p$ is a prime number. We have the
>   $n$-th cartesian product $Z_{p}^{n}=Z_{p} \times ... \times Z_{p}$ and
>   an addition / multiplication is defined by:

[image]

> In short, say why $Z_{p}^{n}$ is a vector space of the dimension $n$ over
>   $Z_{p}$

---

Because of the given things above, I would believe that we have to concentrate on the properties of the addition and scalar multiplication in $Z_{p}$ to show this.

$Z_{p}^{n}$ is a vector space of the dimension $n$ because we have $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ so $n$ is a basis of the vector space $Z_{p}$ and that's why $n$ is the dimension of $Z_{p}$.

Is this reasoning correct because I don't know another way saying this? : /

Comment: Recall that $Z_p$ is a field. Now, for every field $K$, $K^n$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a vector space because it satisfies all the axioms of vector spaces.

---

It has dimension $n$ because $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},\dots
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

forms a basis of the vector space.